# Implementation of a singly linked list

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list

I wonder if the code below is a good (quality and correctness) implementation of a single linked list in C++, in regard of data structure (not the exposed interface).

```
class List
{
  class Node
  {
    friend class List;
    int value;
    Node *next;
  };
  Node *head, *last;

  public:
  int size;
  List()
  {
    head = new Node;
    head->next = 0;
    last = head;
    size = 0;
  }
  ~List()
  {
    Node *it = head, *next;
    while (it)
    {
      next = it->next;
      delete it;
      it = next;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I added the beginner tag based on your description.  If you are aware that C++ provides a linked-list type for you, you should also add the [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with this code (problem of style):

- `Node` is a class with all members public to `List`. Instead of putting everything private, and `List` as a friend, you should do this:

  ```
  class List
  {
    struct Node // struct has everything public
    {
      int value;
      Node *next;
    };
    Node *head, *last;
  ```

  This is less code, and everything in `Node` is invisible outside of `List` anyway, because `List::Node` is private.
- You should use initializer lists for data members, and add a constructor for `Node`:

  ```
  struct Node // has everything public
  {
    int value;
    Node *next;

    Node(int x) : value{ x }, next{ nullptr } {} // <---- here
  };
  ```

  This will allow you to write client code like this:

  ```
  List()
  : head{ new Node(0) }, last{ head }, size{ 0 }
  {
  }
  ```
- I know you said the interface of the classes is not the issue, but this is a big problem:

  ```
  class List
  {
  // ...
    public:    // <---
    int size;  // <---
  ```

  The only way this code is acceptable, is if this client code is valid:

  ```
  List mylist;
  mylist.size = -5; // is this valid? what should it do?
  ```

  If client code is not allowed to alter this value freely, it should not be a public, non-const member of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the public size parameter could be indeed a problem. And I'll also have a read about extended  initializer lists.